# Weird html output of single_cat_title - is not inside of the html element?

Tags: categories, title, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I'm displaying a single "featured" post at the top of the blog index page, and category pages.

I'm using this conditional to display the category name of the category page if it is a category page, or to display one category title of the featured post if it is on the blog index page:

```
if( is_category() ):
    $category = strip_tags( single_cat_title() );
  echo '<div class="title main fs-45">' . $category .'<span></span></div>';
else:
    $category = get_the_category();
  echo '<div class="title main fs-45">' . $category[0]->cat_name .'<span></span></div>';
endif;
```

This conditional works fine for the blog index page.  However, when on a category page, the html result places the category title outside of the `<div class="title main fs-45"></div>`.

For example, on "My Current Category" category page the html result looks like:

```
<div class="widget-box featured beige right">
My Current Category
<div class="title main fs-45"><span></span></div>

    <div class="the-content">

        ... some other html …

    </div>

</div>
```

And on the blog index page, the html result is correct like this:

```
<div class="widget-box featured beige right">

<div class="title main fs-45">Featured Post Category Name<span></span></div>

    <div class="the-content">

        ... some other html …

    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Some function is `echo`ing when it should be `return`ing but without more code I can't say much else.

Comment: Some WordPress functions *return* their output, and some *echo* their output. When this sort of issue comes up, it is *almost always* a case of a function *echoing* output rather than *returning* it as the user intends. I would **highly recommend** *starting with the function's **[Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title)***, and verifying output echo vs. return. (Note: WordPress functions that *return* rather than *echo* their output *almost always* start with `get_`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [`single_cat_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/single_cat_title/), a wrapper for [`single_term_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/single_term_title/), outputs the category name.
Try replacing that call with `single_cat_title('',false)`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!  Replacing `single_cat_title()` with `single_cat_title('',false)` was the fix :)